# Spring boot WAR deployment to tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, war, tomcat8, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have recently started packaging my application as a war.

I have noticed whenever I deploy the application within tomcat, 404 errors are now placed into  tags, where as when deploying as a standalone, the _body response would be in JSON. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Within the tomcat on a war deployment I get the return _body:

```
<.!doctype html><.html lang="en"><.head><.title>HTTP Status 404 – Not Found<./title>
```

On a standalone deployment the return _body =

```
"{"timestamp":"2018-06-26T18:28:38.731+0000","message":"04ed1a7a-729d-48d7-b306-8e9ff6d7a2e0","details":"uri=/api/userSecurity/login","status":4011003}"
```

Is there maybe some sort of tomcat setting that is causing this?

Thank you

Comment: What is the expected output? Maybe this could be helpful: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-deploy-war-file-to-tomcat/

Comment: Thank you for your response, that link was really helpful.

Comment: Cool man, did it solved your problem?

Comment: It did solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The user solved the problem by preparing the application with bootstrap to be deployed in tomcat as [explained here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-deploy-war-file-to-tomcat/).